# How do I make a std::map not need to compare entire strings twice?

Tags: c++, optimization, stdmap

`std::map` makes comparisons by checking if the value being searched for is less than the value currently being compared against, so this means if the `map` keys are strings, it will need to compare the entire strings twice if they're equal.

I tried to get around this by recording the last strings compared, and using the result of the last comparison if the strings are the same. The problem is that I'm pretty sure this isn't thread safe, so I think I would need to use a lock every time I used the `map`.

Is there a better way to do this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <map>

const char* lastComparedlhs = nullptr;
const char* lastComparedrhs = nullptr;
int lastCompResult = 0;

struct ComparerForMap
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
        if (rhs.data() == lastComparedlhs && lhs.data() == lastComparedrhs)
        {
            lastComparedlhs = nullptr;
            lastComparedrhs = nullptr;

            return lastCompResult != 0;
        }

        lastComparedlhs = lhs.data();
        lastComparedrhs = rhs.data();
        lastCompResult = lhs.compare(rhs);

        return lastCompResult < 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> normalMap;
    std::map<std::string, int, ComparerForMap> specialMap;

    std::string str1(10000000, 'a');
    std::string str2(str1);
    
    normalMap[str1] = 123;
    specialMap[str1] = 123;

    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int n1 = normalMap[str2];
    auto stop1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop1 - start1);

    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int n2 = specialMap[str2];
    auto stop2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop2 - start2);

    std::cout << "normalMap: " << duration1.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "specialMap: " << duration2.count() << "\npress enter to exit\n";

    // normalMap: about 4000000 ns
    // specialMap: about 2000000 ns

    char ch = getchar();
}
```

Comment: `How do I make a std::map not need to compare entire strings twice?` I'd say not making them the key of the map. If you are dealing with a 10 million char string, you probably want that to be in heap space anyway, maybe storing pointers to that space, comparing those pointer addresses...

Comment: The perceived problem here is a little naive, because when a map contains many entries, the single extra comparison to check for equality is much less significant than the number of comparisons required to arrive at the tree node being searched. If you want to reduce string comparisons and do not explicitly need your container to be ordered, consider trying out `std::unordered_map`. Otherwise, the above suggestion can be pretty good in _some_ scenarios.

Comment: "*The problem is that I'm pretty sure this isn't thread safe*" - `std::map` isn't thread-safe to begin with, so you would need a lock around it no matter what you do, if you are going to share access to the `map` across thread boundaries. So, include the tracking variables inside that same lock, or else store them in thread-local memory instead.

Comment: @paddy It also needs to check again any time the less-than function returns false. So if the map has the string `'a' * 1000 + 'c'`, and you search for `'a' * 1000 + 'b'`, it will need to compare the full strings twice in that case too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In this case though, it's not thread safe even if all you're ever doing is looking up the values to read them.

Comment: Unless you need lexicographical ordering you should check out `std::unordered_map` as paddy suggested. But if you need such ordering and string comparison is a performance issue then a prefix tree might serve you better. And `operator <=>`.